# How to validate form data using form_validation in codeigniter submitted using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I'm writting a code using CodeIgniter

**ajax**

```
  var formData = {};
  var url      = $(form_id).attr("action");
  $(form_id).find("input[name]").each(function (index, node) {
    formData[node.name] = node.value;
  });
  $(form_id).find('select[name]').each(function (index, node) {
    formData[node.name] = node.value;
  });
  $(form_id).find('textarea[name]').each(function (index, node) {
    formData[node.name] = node.value;
  });
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    data: {
      'formdata': formData
    },
    url: url,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
      if (result.data) {
        make_alert();
      } else {
        $('#error-msg').html(result.message);
      }
    },
    error: function(result) {
     // error code here
    }
  });
```

Which will sent a data `formData` to add function in controller

**add function**

```
$this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required',
        array('required' => 'You must provide a %s.')
);
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required');
```

and this part here receive the `formData` values

```
  $post_data = $this->input->post('formdata');
  $data = array (
    'username' => $post_data['username'],
    'email'    => $post_data ['email'],
    'password' => $post_data ['password']
  );
```

and this part run the validation

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
  $result['message'] = validation_errors();
} else {
  $result['data'] = $this->ion_auth->register($data['identity'], $data['password'], $data['email'], $data['additional_data'], $data['group']);
}
```

which return json

```
echo json_encode($result);
```

before using ajax, the code run smoothly without problem, but when using ajax, the validator return a message saying fields should be **required**, meaning, it doesn't receive form data submitted.

this part,

```
  $data = array (
    'username' => $post_data['username'],
    'email'    => $post_data ['email'],
    'password' => $post_data ['password']
  );
```

when using `var_dump()` on `$data` show it received form data submitted using ajax.

My question is, how to validate this `$data` using form_validation?

Comment: Seems like the data is not passed inside `if(result.data)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cant validate using form_validation library
You should validate manually usin if statement and you will set error message as you want